# jQuery build in logic change

Tags: jquery

I am new to jQuery so could you help me with this one? I have a function that executes only on value change. This is used on building a search. I need to fire the function not only on value change and whenever the value is equal to specific one. My logic in words:"Hide this IDs, if this select[id] has a value or its value is changed - do this if else constrution" Can you help me rebuild it to fires on both cases? I think some mashup between `.change` and `.val` functions might help here.

```
<script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

            $("#other_field_id").hide();
            $("#some_field_id").hide();

            $("select[id=what_to_show]").change(function(){

                var myvalue = $("select[id=what_to_show]").val();

                if (myvalue == 'other-value'){                  
                    $("#other_field_id").show();
                }
                else if (myvalue == 'some-value'){
                    $("#some_field_id").show();     
                }               
            });             
        });
</script>
```

Comment: whether the ajax request is replacing the original select element?

Comment: Please re-word you question as it doesn't make a whole lot of sense. What GET request? If you want people to provide assistance you should try and make it as clear as possible what the problem is.

Comment: @ArunPJohny I am not sure I understand you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify to below code

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {         

     $("select[id=what_to_show]").change(function(){
            $("#other_field_id").hide();
            $("#some_field_id").hide();

                var myvalue = $("select[id=what_to_show]").val();

                if (myvalue == 'other-value'){                  
                    $("#other_field_id").show();
                }
                else if (myvalue == 'some-value'){
                    $("#some_field_id").show();     
                }               
            });             
        });
```

Thing you have done wrong is you are hiding the values only at time of document load but not on changing value.

Comment: There is only one problem in this option. When submiting the form there is no change and nothing is triggering.

Comment: do you have your code in fiddle?? if yes please share the link